# Cumulative percentage addition in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, sum, window-functions

i have a scenario where i need to find the percentage difference to each consecutive months, Is there a way to achieve it(Postgresql Version 11)

Is there a way we can get the OUTPUT as shown, there are lot of months and products.

Below is the input.

```
 Name        Date       Quantity
"0009-bio"  "2020-03"   158.0000
"0009-bio"  "2020-04"   
"0009-bio"  "2020-05"   
"0009-bio"  "2020-06"   
"0009-bio"  "2020-07"   
"0009-bio"  "2020-08"   
"0009-bio"  "2020-09"   
"0009-bio"  "2020-10"   
"0009-bio"  "2020-11"   
"0009-bio"  "2020-12"   
"0009-bio"  "2021-01"   
"0009-bio"  "2021-02"   
"0009-bio"  "2021-03"   
"0009-bio"  "2021-04"       
"0014".     "2020-03"   112.0000
"0014"      "2020-04"   
"0014"      "2020-05"   
"0014"      "2020-06"   
"0014"      "2020-07"   
"0014"      "2020-08"
```

**Expected output:**

```
Name        Date       Quantity
"0009-bio"  "2020-03"   158
"0009-bio"  "2020-04"   158 + 20% = 158+31.6=189.6
"0009-bio"  "2020-05"   189.6 +20% ie, 227.52
"0009-bio"  "2020-06"   227.52 +20% ie,273.02
"0009-bio"  "2020-07"   273.02 + 20%

"0014".     "2020-03"   112
"0014"      "2020-04"   112+ 20%
"0014"      "2020-05"   ..
"0014"      "2020-06"   ..
"0014"      "2020-07"   ..
"0014"      "2020-08"   ..
```

Comment: Is there always only _one_ non-null `quantity` for each `name`?

Comment: @mustaccio Yes,as of now only the first row ie, 2020-03 March have values

Comment: @mustaccioIs there a solution for this, any help or suggestion will be of greta help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you could just use window functions and arithmetics:

```
select
    name,
    date,
    first_value(quantity) over(partition by name order by date)
    * power(1.2, row_number() over(partition by name order by date) - 1) quantity
from mytable t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=9446153aa5d65d08697e688ed5e9c96e)**:

```
name     | date    |                  quantity
:------- | :------ | ------------------------:
0009-bio | 2020-03 |  158.00000000000000000000
0009-bio | 2020-04 |  189.60000000000000000000
0009-bio | 2020-05 |  227.52000000000000000000
0009-bio | 2020-06 |  273.02400000000000000000
0009-bio | 2020-07 |  327.62880000000000000000
0009-bio | 2020-08 |  393.15456000000000000000
0009-bio | 2020-09 |  471.78547200000000000000
0009-bio | 2020-10 |  566.14256640000000000000
0009-bio | 2020-11 |  679.37107968000000000000
0009-bio | 2020-12 |  815.24529561600000000000
0009-bio | 2021-01 |  978.29435473920000000000
0009-bio | 2021-02 | 1173.95322568704000000000
0009-bio | 2021-03 | 1408.74387082444800000000
0009-bio | 2021-04 | 1690.49264498933760000000
0014     | 2020-03 |  112.00000000000000000000
0014     | 2020-04 |  134.40000000000000000000
0014     | 2020-05 |  161.28000000000000000000
0014     | 2020-06 |  193.53600000000000000000
0014     | 2020-07 |  232.24320000000000000000
0014     | 2020-08 |  278.69184000000000000000
```